# cannot save changes of a partial view asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

classes

```
class Address
{
    public int customerId {get;set;}
    public string street {get;set;}
    public string state {get;set;}
}

class Customer
{
    public int customerId {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public Address address {get;set;} 
}
```

customer view :

```
@model Models.Customer

@using (Html.BeginForm() 
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.curtomerId
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name)

   @Html.Partial("_Edit", Model)

   <button type="submit">Submit</button>

}
```

partial:

```
@model Models.Customer

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Address.customerId
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address.street)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address.state)
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult customer(Customer c)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(c).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

                Address address = db.Address.Single(x => x.customerId== c.Address.customerId);  
                address = c.Address;        
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

}
```

I can see that all info is being passed to the controller, but ony with the

```
 db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
 db.SaveChanges();
```

I only get the customer updated. 
So I added:

```
 Address address = db.Address.Single(x => x.id == c.Address.Id);   
 address = c.Address;
 db.SaveChanges();
```

But the address information is not being saved, I have no idea why.

Comment: Where is the linee you have assigned or used `c`?

Comment: And you can use `db.SaveChanges()` once. It is not the problem but just a suggestion

Comment: sorry, it's customer c, not model.

Answer (score 0):

The `Address` entity was retrieved and assigned to the `address` variable. Then the `address` variable is re-assigned to `c.Address.` The address you retrieved from the DB is on the context but was not modified, and doesn't have a reference in your scope anymore.

If you set the properties of the `address` entity you retrieved to the properties of `c.Address` then it would be marked modified if there were changes.

```
address.street = c.Address.street;
address.state = c.Address.state;
```

If you check the `State` of the address entity you retrieved, presumably you'd see it as `EntityState.Modified` at that point.